# R: NA on mean for a numerical variable

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, mean

I am trying to determine some values based on cellular carrier. I have a main data frame that contains data from all carriers, and I have created 3 individual data frames from the main data frame by provider:

```
verizondf <- maindata[maindata$network == "Verizon",]
attdf <- maindata[maindata$network=="ATT",]
tmobiledf <- maindata[maindata$network=="TMobile",]
```

I want to get the average for one of the variables, "download", which is a numerical value.

On the verizondf data frame, it works fine:

```
> mean(verizondf$download)
[1] 462004.4
```

For the other 2, I get NA:

```
> mean(attdf$download)
[1] NA
```

I wondered if the data type had changed at some point, but I checked and it is still numeric:

```
> str(attdf$download)
 num [1:5516] 321585 50722 400085 287968 138301 ...
```

What could be causing this issue?

Comment: Are there any NA values in the data?

Comment: add `na.rm=T` `mean(attdf$download,na.rm=T)`

Comment: mean(attdf$download, na.rm=TRUE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have pointed this out with their comments, I can give a "fuller" explanation here.

When you look at the help manual pages using `?mean` you will get the description, including this info:

> Usage
>
> mean(x, ...)
>
> ## Default S3 method:
>      mean(x, trim = 0, na.rm = FALSE, ...)

Looking under the "Arguments" section, you will see this:

> **na.rm**
>      a logical value indicating whether NA values should be stripped before the >    computation proceeds.

This tells you that the default for `mean` is to *not* strip out NA's, which will lead to a mean of NA if your data contains NA's.

If you want a numeric mean computed when you have NA values (and this is ok, given the fact you have NA's...something that is **not** always true!!!) you would use `mean` with the argument `na.rm = TRUE`.